# Get the Sum of the multiplication from 2 different tables depending upon an id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to get the sum of all the bill for a defined client, the multiplication depend of the id of the sell

Tables 1

```
bill  id     Amount
1     KM     3
2     NUI    7
3     ETP    11
```

Tables 2

```
ID      Price
ETP     110
KM      15
NUI     80
```

For example, in this situation, I have to got 3 * 15 + 7 * 80 + 11 * 110

the request have to return 1815.

someone can help me ? I really don't know how to do this ...

Comment: You can use pre-query concept to find your result.  like below code
`select sum(client_amount) as total_amount
from 
( select (t1.Amount * t2.Price) as client_amount 
 from Table1 as t1 
 inner join Table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.ID
 ) as preq`
I haven't run this on database but it should give your desired result

Answer (score 5):

This is a `join` query with aggregation:

```
select sum(t1.amount * t2.price)
from t1 join
     t2
     using (id);
```